# php mailer having authentication error godadday

Tags: php

I am using goddady server and having email id integrated with outlook web app, and i am using smtp php mailer to send form records to email id, but records are not received on my email id, it gives following error,

```
> Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password:
> NO)
```

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: The username and password are either incorrect, or they don't have permission to access the smtp server.  Simples!

Comment: which username, password should i use

Comment: You need to find out from Godaddy. Don't you set up your own email accounts on their website?